# How to calculate average asymptotic running time in Big-O notation?

Tags: c++, performance, big-o, complexity-theory

Trying to understand Asymptotic notations which I understand is used to describe performance of an algorithm. Am I correct in saying that there is worst, best and average case scenarios? So for example, for the following piece of code, what is the average asymptotic running time in Big-O notation?

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i + j);
    }
}
```

Would it be O(n^2)?

Comment: Assuming you mean time complexity as a function of `size`, then it doesn't make sense to distinguish best-case/worst-cast/average-case, because there is only one possible input for any given `size` in your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in saying that there is worst, best and average case scenarios?

Generally only worst case and average case are of interest, but you can consider the best case as well if you prefer.

> Would it be O(n^2)?

What you have there is a typical `O(n^2)` complexity, yes. Best, average and worst, they're all the same for your particular case. They're only not the same if you can break out of loops early, or conditionally skip entire loops.

Edit: Example of when the average and best case complexity are different:

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
  if(arr[i] == needle)
    return needle;
```

This is at best a constant operation, ie O(1), if the element is found right away, and at worst an O(n) linear operation -- a linear search specifically.

Comment: I see. Could you possibly provide a code example where worst case and average cases are different? If not, are there any specific resources you can point me towards to help me understand this in more detail?

Comment: Different worst and average complexities is a bit more difficult, but I edited in an example of different best and average/worst complexity. The former is more difficult because asymptotic complexity is designed to be pretty pessimistic to begin with.

Comment: @AaySquare quicksort has worst-case complexity O(n^2) and average-case complexity O(n log n). If choosing pivots with randomization it is unlikely, but possible, that the random choices will result in worst-case behavior for any particular input.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in saying that there is worst, best and average case scenarios?

A case is just some subset of all possible inputs, possibly a subset that has one input of all possible input sizes. So for instances, a case for a sorting algorithm might be some subset of the set of all possible input arrays, and maybe just those subsets that have exactly one element of each input size. Using this definition, the worst case would be the subset of inputs such that they cause the algorithm to execute the most instructions for the given input size; the best case would be the set of inputs that require the least number of steps at each input size; and the average case would be like the expected value of running types over all possible instances at each size (by the simple definition above, the average "case" is not really a true case at all, more like a hypothetical case).

To every case we may associate an asymptotic bound - upper, lower, or both. Typically of interest are upper bounds on the worst-case, and sometimes lower-bounds on the best-case. But it's not incorrect to speak of an upper bound on the best case or a lower bound on the worst case.

The code you've posted always does an amount of work proportional to the square of `size`'s value. In that sense it is `O(size^2)`. It is also Omega and Theta of `size^2`. If the algorithm gets input whose size in bits is proportional to size, then this is the true complexity. If the algorithm gets the value of `size` as input (represented using `log(size)` bits) then the complexity is actually exponential - the complexity in terms of `size` might be called *pseudopolynomial*.